# Python trouble with repeater

Tags: python

Im trying to write a program so that I get a result of...

```
5 : Rowan
6 : Rowan
7 : Rowan
8 : Rowan
9 : Rowan
10 : Rowan
11 : Rowan
12 : Rowan
```

I want to be able to set it so that I can change the starting number, the amount of times it repeats and the word that it repeats.

this is what i have so far...

```
def hii(howMany, start, Word):
    Word 
    for howMany in range (howMany):
         print howMany + start, ":", "-"
```

Im just having trouble making it so i can change the word that repeats

Answer (score 3):

The `range` iterator takes a start value:

```
def hii(howMany, start, Word):
    for i in range(start, start+howMany):
        print i, ":", Word
```

Note that it's not a good idea to use the same name for a local variable as for a parameter (`howMany`). I have used `i` instead.

Answer (score 1):

From Python 2.6 upwards enumerate has a start parameter:

```
import itertools

def hii(how_many, start, word):
    seq = itertools.repeat(word, how_many)
    return enumerate(seq, start=start)

for n, w in hii(8, 5, 'Rowan'):
    print n, w
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def hii(howMany, start, Word):
    for howMany in range (howMany):
         print howMany + start, ":", Word
```

Is there anything wrong with that?

To use:

```
hii(10, 4, "Weeee!!!!")
```

Comment: it doesnt work if i do that and try changing the value of Word to say newyork it says that newyork is not defined

Comment: Pass the word as 'newyork' (with quotes).

Answer (score 0):

***python 2.x***

```
>>> def repeater(start, end, word):
...  for i in range(start, end):
...   print i, ":", word
>>> repeater(2,8, "hello")
```

***for python3.x***

```
>>> def repeater(start, end, word):
... for i in range(start, end):
...  print(i , ":" , word)
>>> repeater(2,8, "hello")
```